# Why div with width and without float is o the next line?

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>float</title>
  <style>
   .layer1 {
    float: left; /* Обтекание по правому краю */
    background: #fd0; /* Цвет фона */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Параметры рамки */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    margin-right: 20px; /* Отступ справа */
    width: 40%; /* Ширина блока */
   }
   .layer2 {
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="layer1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh 
   euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div class="layer2">
   Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel 
   illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio 
   dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit au gue duis dolore te 
   feugat nulla facilisi.
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My question is the following: If layer 2 has floating then two my divs are the same line; if I remove floating from layer2 and leave only width this div will be transferred to the next line. Why?

Also, I'm a beginner in the frontend, I need to learn it. What books/cources can help me to study? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" here is not one, it's standard floating behaviour. Check my snippet to see where `.layer2` really is located. `.layer2` actually begins on the same x-coordinate as `.layer1`, otherwise it wouldn't be floating around `.layer1`, but it would rather be a new column. If that is what you wish, you need to give `layer2` a margin-left of just as many pixels as `.layer2`'s width.

```css
.layer1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(255, 230, 240, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
}
.layer2 {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
  width: 80px;
}
.additionalClass {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div class="layer2">
  Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat.</div>

<div class="layer1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div class="layer2 additionalClass">
  Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit au gue duis dolore te feugat nulla facilisi.
</div>
```

Other than that, it is important to know that `<div>` belongs to the so-called *block level elements*. As such it has several standard behaviours, one of them is to wrap to a new line before it and to a new line after it.

Another standard behaviour for block level elements for example is that if you don't specify either `width` or `max-width`, it grabs all the space it can get horizontally.

Both these standard behaviours are lost if you apply either `float: left;` or `float: right;` to the element.

Comment: I understand floating; but layout2 won't go on next line if I don't set width to him; and go if I set - why?

Comment: Check the snippet and my explanation again.

Comment: OK, I mean the following: if layout2 HAVE ONLY width attribute it will go to the next line; if layout2 DOESN'T HAVE any style it will stay on the same line - why?

Comment: As long as you don't float, `.layer2` behaves identical, doesn't matter if you apply a width or not. But if you apply `width: 30px` obviously the text cannot be right of your `.layer1`. Apply `width: 75%;` to `.layer1` and you see it does NOT wrap to a new line (which I wanted to demonstate in my snippet using semi-transparent background-colors). Not applying any width basically means that `.layer2` has `width: 100%;` (which is, as I explained one of the standard behaviours of block level elements).

Comment: And no, so far you definitely do not understand floating. Read more about it: http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa010107.htm

Comment: @Connexo Could you do me a huge favor and check your first paragraph again? It seems your `.layer1`s and `.layer2`s got a little jumbled up.

Answer (score 0):

Since div is a block element it occupies line by line.

Comment: I understand floating; but layout2 won't go on next line if I don't set width to him; and go if I set - why?